# How to implement clock like functionality in the "quiz" like form

Tags: php, forms, clock

Hi I am a PHP noob and I have been working on this PHP quiz application for my college project.

I have a database of questions and a PHP view page which will load a question from the database and when the user clicks the submit button.

It will then submit the form; on the server side it first stores the id of this question in the session so repetition of questions does not occur, check the answer of the question, and depending upon whether the response was correct or incorrect, an appropriate message will be transferred to the client side along with the current score and other details.

**What I want now is a clock-like functionality which will automatically do something should the user run out of time.**

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to look for using `setTimeout` in `javascript` which runs the clock in client-side. Also you need to take care of tracking the starttime of the test in PHP `$_SESSION` and verify the submission in server-side.